# Defining query analyzer in RavenDB

Tags: lucene, ravendb, analyzer

I have created an index with the Standard Analyzer.
I understand that in Lucene you can define the analyzer used to parse the query as well so it will match the analyzer of the index.

How can it be done with RavenDB?

Answer (score 1):

You define you analyzer, then you register that for the field in question (you need to provide the assembly qualified name).

Comment: Can you please give an example how it is done? Is it per query or done also in server side?

Comment: It is all in the docs http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/configuring-index-options